# update values in nested dict based on key

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary and I want to update the value of an item based on its key value.
For example, I have the following dictionary and I want to set the value of every occurrence of an item with key=='p' to be 1.

```
my_dict = {'p': 0, 'nested_dict': {'p': 0, 'a': 2}}
```

For a regular dictionary (non-nested) the *update* method provides a simple one-liner solution:

```
my_dict.update((x, 1) for x, y in my_dict.items() if x=='p')
```

I'm looking for a similar solution for the case of nested dictionary

Comment: we are talking arbitrarily nested or is the max depth known?

Comment: arbitrary depth, I think this implies applying some kind of recursion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the max depth of the dictionary is known and constant and the `'p'`s always appear at the same depth this can be solved without recursion. In all other cases, a recursive approach is needed. Based on the example problem and your comments, I will assume that the second one is true. Here is a recursive solution:

```
def setPto1(dct):
    return {k: setPto1(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else [v, 1][k=='p'] for k, v in dct.items()}
```

So you basically loop through the key-value pairs with a recursive dictionary comprehension. You were not far off with your approach. If there is something you do not understand about it, leave a comment.

If `[v, 1][k=='p']` makes you feel uneasy, you can replace it with the more straight-forward `(1 if k=='p' else v)`. They are the same thing.

Comment: `[v, 1][k=='p']` looks fancy-numpy-ish?

Comment: fancy sure, but I would not say `numpy`ish; it is just basic boolean indexing. `numpy` has a much more powerful boolean indexing engine that operates similarly to `filter`.

Comment: Thanks!, personally, I like this  `[v, 1][k=='p']` style

Comment: Its a matter of taste as long as you understand it. Note however that it might be a bit more costly in terms of computer resources since Python needs to build the `[v, 1]` list. Feel free to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @PatrickArtner This syntax, though requiring some adaptation, is quite nice. Since which version of python is it available? What's the exact name for this syntax?

Comment: @deponovo - was not my idea - but it is essentially a ternary `result =   ..... IF condition ELSE .....`   and the else part is `[v ,1][k=='p']`.  `k=='p'` is either True (1) or False (0) and indexes into the list before it (use position 0 or 1 of the list based on truthyness) - you could also index into a tuple `(v,1)[k=='p']` .  You can do that kind of stuff since python 2.xxxxx whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could get you started (you can still make it more generic, and it might have problems with repeated keys):

```
from functools import reduce

def decision_func(d, item, replace_on_item, replace_val):
    if item == replace_on_item:
        d[item] = replace_val
    else:
        return d[item]

my_dict = {'p': 0, 'nested_dict': {'p': 0, 'a': 2}}
reduce(lambda d, item: decision_func(d, item, 'p', ["some_other_val", 2]), ['nested_dict', 'p'], my_dict)
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'p': 0, 'nested_dict': {'p': ['some_other_val', 2], 'a': 2}}
```

What is done here is that you are going to run down the nesting tree by using the `reduce` function, and the `decision_func` is the one making the decision on whether to update a given entry or return the value for that key and continue looking for the next nesting level (basically a recursion prob). Note that as written above, this is not yet a bullet proof implementation.